# Why does Rails use the base class name, and not the subclass name, with polymorphic associations and STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have Single Table Inheritance with `BuyerInvoice` inheriting from `Invoice`.

If I assign such an invoice to a polymorphic association, Rails will store e.g. `record_type: "Invoice"` rather than `record_type: "BuyerInvoice"`. It stores `record.class.base_class.name`.

What are some reasons they may have done this? I'm implementing something vaguely similar and would like to understand why Rails might have made that decision.

Best I can think of is that it makes it a bit easier to rename subclasses without affecting associations, though doing it the other way would make it easier to rename abstract superclasses…

Comment: Half of the point of STI is to avoid polymorphic assocations.

Comment: @max It can avoid some polymorphic associations but not others (`bookable.record_type/id` where the record is e.g. an invoice or a payment). And the fact remains that Rails handles polymorphic STI in this way, so the question stands :)

Answer (score 1):

STI is an implementation detail of a model, it should not leak into its relations.

Other than renaming subclasses:

- STI can be implemented with custom class resolution (with type column not being a class name at all), even have some weird cases where class changes dynamically based on attributes etc.
- STI can be added to a model after it already has relations
- STI can be removed at all

Comment: Thank you! Good points. About the "STI can be removed" point – I guess it depends on how you remove it. If I later break "BuyerInvoice" into its table, I need to change the existing polymorphic associations if it stores the "Invoice" base class now.

Comment: @HenrikN yes, sure it depends on exact case, I meant removal in favour of a single universal class while keeping the db schema and data intact. If you split `invoices` table into two - you already have to modify both structure and data, so it's logical that associations should be modified as well

Comment: Another reason I thought of – not sure if there's a real application for this, but – if Rails ever needs to find a bunch of associated records and wants to do so with the least amount of queries, then storing the base class lets it make a single query (`Invoice.where(id: a_bunch_of_associated_ids)`) rather than one per subclass.